# Behavior of the 'return' statement in Bash functions

Tags: bash, function, return

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of the `return` built-in in Bash. Here is a sample script.

```
#!/bin/bash

dostuff() {
    date | while true; do
        echo returning 0
        return 0
        echo really-notreached
    done

    echo notreached
    return 3
}

dostuff
echo returncode: $?
```

The output of this script is:

```
returning 0
notreached
returncode: 3
```

If, however, the `date |`  is removed from line 4, the output is as I expected:

```
returning 0
returncode: 0
```

It seems like the `return` statement as used above is acting the way I thought the `break` statement ought to behave, but only when the loop is on the right hand side of a pipe. Why is this the case? I couldn't find anything to explain this behavior in the [Bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or online. The script acts the same way in Bash 4.1.5 and [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash:_Ubuntu,_Debian_and_POSIX_compliance_of_Linux_distributions) 0.5.5.

Comment: Interesting. Yes it seems that return behaves a bit like break; also with returns inside if statements you can see this happens. Unless the if expression is VERY simple.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the `date | while ...` scenario, that while loop is executed in a subshell due to the presence of the pipe. Thus, the return statement breaks the loop and the *subshell* ends, leaving your function to carry on.

You'll have to reconstruct the code to remove the pipeline so that no subshells are created:

```
dostuff() {
    # redirect from a process substitution instead of a pipeline
    while true; do
        echo returning 0
        return 0
        echo really-notreached
    done < <(date)

    echo notreached
    return 3
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you `return` inside a function, that function will stop executing but the overall program will not exit.

If you `exit` inside a function, the overall program will exit.

You cannot `return` in the main body of a Bash script. You can only `return` inside a function or sourced script.

---

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function doSomething {
    echo "a"
    return
    echo "b"  # this will not execute because it is after 'return'
}

function doSomethingElse {
    echo "d"
    exit 0
    echo "e"  # this will not execute because the program has exited
}

doSomething
echo "c"
doSomethingElse
echo "f"  # this will not execute because the program exited in 'doSomethingElse'
```

Running the above code will output:

```
a
c
d
```

Comment: The original question *is* returning inside a function, so while this answer is informative then it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

But `return` should terminate a function call, not a subshell. `exit` is intended to terminate (sub)shell. I think, it's some undocumented bug/feature.

- `echo | return` typed in a commandline gives an error. That's correct - `return` should be in a function.
- `f(){ echo|return; }` is accepted in the Bash and [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash:_Ubuntu,_Debian_and_POSIX_compliance_of_Linux_distributions), but `return` doesn't terminate a function call.

If `return` terminates a subshell, it would work outside a function. So, the conclusion is: **`return` terminates a subshell in a function** which is strange.

Comment: Here's a demo that supports the conclusion: `function foo { echo start function; ( echo start subshell; return; echo end subshell); echo end function; }`

Comment: This seems to be a good explaination. Simple expressions in if or while statements will not cause a subshell to run so return will behave as ~normal/expected~. More complex expressions (e.g. use variable in expression) will cause subshell so return looks like it behaves as a break;.

Answer (score 2):

To cover this interesting feature of Bash...

- return inside *if* (or any control command with expression like if/while/...)
- return inside *if* with simple and less simple expressions

The subshell explanation is good. Control returns out of the current subshell. Which might be the Bash function. Or it might be any of the nested control commands with an expression which has caused a subshell to be invoked.

1. for very simple expressions, e.g., "true" or "1 == 1" there is no subshell invoked. So *return* behaves as ~normal/expected~.
2. for less simple expressions, e.g., variable expanded and compared with something then *return* behaves like *break*;

*Simple* (no subshell) examples:

```
$ rtest () { if true; then echo one; return 2; echo two; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest
one
$ echo $?
2

$ rtest () { if [[ 1 == 1 ]] ; then echo one; return 2; echo two; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest
one
$ echo $?
2

$ rtest () { if [[ 1 =~ 1 ]] ; then echo one; return 2; echo two; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest
one
$ echo $?
2

$ rtest () { if $DO ; then echo one; return 2; echo two; else echo three; return 3; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest
one
$ echo $?
2

$ rtest () { if [[ $DO ]]; then echo one; return 2; echo two; else echo three; return 3; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest
three
$ echo $?
3

$ rtest () { if [[ $DO == 1 ]] ; then echo one; return 2; echo two; else echo three; return 3; echo four; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest; echo $?
one
2
$ DO=1; rtest; echo $?
one
2
$ DO=0; rtest; echo $?
three
3
```

Expression not simple and presuming subshell is invoked, *return* behaviour is like *break*;

*Not simple* (subshell) example ... `=~` inside `[[ ]]`:

```
$ rtest () { if [[ $DO =~ 1 ]] ; then echo one; return 2; echo two; fi; echo not simple; return 7; }
$ rtest
not simple
$ echo $?
7
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: the subshell is a separate process.
It doesn't really have a way to say to the parent shell: "I'm exiting because of a return"

There is no such thing in the exit status, which is the only thing the parent shell gets.